# Safe way to initialize attributes from a yaml or hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my initialize method I am trying to write it so I can pass either a hash or a yaml object to init the attribute values.

My yaml file looks like:

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost
  port: 4565
  timeout: 3


development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

staging:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

I currently have this:

```
def initialize(options)

  if options.respond_to? "has_key" && options.has_key? "defaults"
    config = options["defaults"]
  else
    config = options
  end

  @hostname = config[:hostname]
  @port = config[:port]
  @timeout = config[:timeout]

end
```

This is currently not working for me, I'm getting this error:

```
unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
      if options.respond_to? "has_key" && options.has_key? "defaults"
```

1. How can I load the correct environment also? (test, development, production)
2. How can I throw an error if one of the keys isn't present? (or say at least the major ones that I need for sure like hostname, port)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parenthesize your if statement.

```
if options.respond_to?("has_key") && options.has_key?("defaults")
```

Comment: spaces seem to matter also? confused, didn't expect this!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the following code?

```
  if options.respond_to? "has_key" && options.has_key? "defaults"
    config = options["defaults"]
  else
    config = options
  end
```

The yaml file is structured in the way that all four groups (development, test, staging, production) will have the default keys, they won't be nested under `default` key. It is basically equivalent to this:

```
development:
  host: localhost
  port: 4565
  timeout: 3

test:
  host: localhost
  port: 4565
  timeout: 3

#...
```

Comment: I see default in mine though.

Comment: I guess you are passing yaml[:development] as options, there won't be :defaults key in that hash.